# How to set 'Redirect URIs' in the service settings in Hub

Tags: jetbrains-ide, upsource

I can access upsource locally using `http://pcname:42424/projectname/view`.

Trying to access it using the IP eg. `http://192.168.1.42:42424/projectname/view` yields

> OAuth 2.0 Error
>
> unauthorized_client: Unregistered Redirect URI. Client service
>   'Upsource' requests authorization entity for the URI which is not
>   registered in Hub: http://192.168.3.143:42424/. If you have Hub
>   administrator permissions and the suspicious URI does belong to
>   'Upsource', please add this URI to the list of 'Redirect URIs' in the
>   service settings in Hub

With link to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/2.0/OAuth-2.0-Errors.html#auth.unauthorized_client

I could not find how to set `redirectUri` though in Upsource (went through maybe all of the settings pages).

Where can I find the `redirectUri` setting so I can add my IP to it?

**Update**

I set up another instance on a different box and set the URL and port to be `http://192.168.1.42:42424` and now it works successfully to be accessed remotely using the IP.

Comment: Did you ever figure out where in Hub to set this?

Comment: @Brandon I don't think I found the setting in the end. I ran through the set-up process again to set the IP/port.

Comment: I figured it out... I'll add an answer

Answer (score 9):

For some reason the redirect URI settings area is hidden in Hub even if you're an administrator. I was searching for something else in the JetBrains knowledge base and came across [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/2.0/OAuth-2.0-Authorization.html#d66870e314) which led me to try to add `/services` to the end of my hub url in my browser:

> http://my.serverurl.up/hub/services

Which brings me to this wonderous page with a bunch of configuration options that I can't access through the Administration UI:

[image]

FWIW: What I was trying to do initially was configure UpSource to be accessed through a reverse proxy on port 80, instead of the default 8080. I moved my UpSource configuration from one server to another and read the [documentation from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/2.0/proxy_configuration.html) on the subject but it wasn't working.

My mistake: I didn't stop UpSource before running

`<upsource_home>\bin\upsource.sh configure --listen-port 1111 --base-url http://upsource.mydomain.com:2222`

and **UpSource didn't warn me** that the command wasn't doing anything. Its message was "UpSource is now running". I stopped UpSource, applied the change and restarted and everything worked. I should've known but I didn't.

Hope that helps someone.